# Digispark Read Capslock Status

Tags: arduino, hid, capslock

I am very new to the digispark and I am only partly familiar with the `DigisparkKeyboard\digikeyboard.h` library.

I am able to send keystrokes to the PC, but I also want to check whether <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> is active on the host machine and also be notified when it's pressed.

Comment: **FYI:** There's a DigisparkKeyboard fork by [Danjovic](https://github.com/Danjovic/DigistumpArduino/tree/master/digistump-avr/libraries/DigisparkKeyboard) that allows you check keyboard leds. For more information, see this [hackaday.io post](https://hackaday.io/page/6947-digikeyboard-with-leds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not directly possible using existing Arduino Libraries or Digispark Libraries.

But, [here](https://github.com/yuvadm/digispark-projects/tree/master/keyboard) is a crude solution written in C. If you want to see actual implementation then refer [this](http://codeandlife.com/2012/06/18/usb-hid-keyboard-with-v-usb/)

Answer (score 0):

The DigiKeyboard.h library is write only (from Digispark to PC).

No way to read keyboard status (CAPSLOCK , NUMLOCK) back.

(BTW: Which status do you want to read: the digispark or another 'real' keyboard, on a different USB or PS/2 port ?)